# Is there is any support for Single Table Inheritance in Prisma?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, prisma, single-table-inheritance

I have one project in Rails where I used  Single Table Inheritance on Users Table, by creating two roles for Users table - 1.Clinician and 2.Patient. The model desc. is below

class Patient < User
has_many :clinician_patients
has_many :clinicians, through: :clinician_patients
end

class Clinician < User
has_many :clinician_patients
has_many :patients, through: :clinician_patients
end

Here I have another table clinician_patients :-

class ClinicianPatient < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :clinician
belongs_to :patient
end

I am new to Prisma and I want to use STI and relationships like Rails in Node using Prisma. How should I use STI in prisma models?

Answer (score 3):

As you can see [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/database-features#misc) prisma does not support table inheritance yet, but support is planned in the future.

There are some shim implementations you can try out until there is an official implementation:

- https://github.com/smcelhinney/prisma-merge-schema
- https://github.com/amplication/prisma-schema-dsl